# Which operations preserve order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

**TL;DR;** I am looking for a place where I can lookup whether a certain intermediate or terminal operation. Where can I find such documentation?

**Edit** This is not a duplicate of [How to ensure order of processing in java8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216588/), since that question does not provide a comprehensive list of operations.

## Background

The [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) says:

> Whether or not a stream has an encounter order depends on the source and the intermediate operations

Which is repeated in [this excellent stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/722929)

> In order to ensure maintenance of ordering throughout an entire stream operation, you have to study the documentation of the stream’s source, all intermediate operations and the terminal operation for whether they maintain the order or not (or whether the source has an ordering in the first place).

That is all well and good, but which documentation should I look at? The [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) mentions in an example that `map` guarantees ordering, but it doesn't have a exhaustive list. The [javadoc for the Stream class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) documents some intermediate operations, but not all.
Take for example [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

or [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

None of these describe whether they preserve ordering.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35664976/722929) claims:

> Actually every intermediate operation preserves an order by default. The only exceptions are:
>
> - unordered() which removes the ordering constraint.
> - sorted() which changes the order.
>
> When it's not explicitly specified, you can assume that operation keeps the order. Even distinct() keeps the order, though it adds much complexity for parallel stream.

but is there any official documentation to back that up?

## Extra credit

The is actually has two separate ordering issues.

1. Does the output of the operation maintain the same ordering as the input?
2. Is the operation executed in-order on each element.

For example, a parallel `map` operation could go over all elements in an arbitrary order (violating 2.), but still maintain order in the returned stream  (obeying 1.)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/32453

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some researching in the source code I summarized the following tables:

Taken from: [Java streams - Part 6 - Spliterator](https://github.com/stavalfi/lectures/blob/master/Java%20Streams%20-%20Series/Java%20streams%20-%20Part%206%20-%20Spliterator.md)

The following table showes which operations types are allowed to modify charactersiticts:

```
|                        | DISTICTS | SORTED | ORDERED | SIZED | SHORT_CIRCUIT |
| ---------------------- | -------- | ------ | ------- | ----- | --------------|
| source stream          | Y        | Y      | Y       | Y     | N             |
| intermediate operation | PCI      | PCI    | PCI     | PC    | PI            |
| terminal operation     | N        | N      | PC      | N     | PI            |
```

- Y - Allowed to have
- P - May preserves
- C - May clears.
- I - May injects.
- N - Not valid; Irelevant for the operation.

---

Taken from [Java streams - Stream methods characteristics table](https://github.com/stavalfi/lectures/tree/master/Java%20Streams%20-%20Series#stream-methods-characteristics-table)

The following table showes which characteristics and flags each *intermediate operation*/*terminal operation* may turns on and off: (`SHORT_CIRCUIT` is relevent only in the context of `StreamOpFlag` flags)

**Note: `P` (Preserve) flag is added to every cell except the ones with the `C` and `I` (Clear and Inject) flags.**

```
|                  |  DISTINCT |  SORTED |  ORDERED |  SIZED |  SHORT_CIRCUIT |
| ---------------- | ----------| --------| ---------| -------| ---------------|
|  filter          |           |         |          |  C     |                |
|  forEach         |           |         |  C       |        |                |
|  forEachOrdered  |           |         |          |        |                |
|  allMatch        |           |         |  C       |        |  I             |
|  distinct        |  I        |         |          |  C     |                |
|  flatMap         |  C        |  C      |          |  C     |                |
|  anyMatch        |           |         |  C       |        |  I             |
|  collect         |           |         |          |        |                |
|  unOrdered       |           |         |  C       |        |                |
|  count           |  C        |  C      |  C       |  C     |                |
|  findAny         |           |         |  C       |        |  I             |
|  findFirst       |           |         |          |        |  I             |
|  flatMapToXXX    |  C        |  C      |          |  C     |                |
|  limit           |           |         |          |  C     |  I             |
|  map             |  C        |  C      |          |        |                |
|  mapToXXX        |  C        |  C      |          |        |                |
|  max             |           |         |          |        |                |
|  min             |           |         |          |        |                |
|  noneMatch       |           |         |  C       |        |  I             |
|  peek            |           |         |          |        |                |
|  reduce          |           |         |          |        |                |
|  skip            |           |         |  C       |  I     |                |
|  sorted          |           |  I      |  I       |        |                |
|  toArray         |           |         |          |        |                |
```

- `C` - Clears.
- `I` - Injects.

Comment: I fixed some of these flags; first of all, the fundamental difference between `forEach` and `forEachOrdered` is that `forEach` does not respect the order, per contract, even if the current implementation might not clear the flag internally; this set/clear logic isn’t really suitable to terminal operations. Further, there is no reason why the order of elements should be relevant to the `count` operation, which can be short circuiting in Java 9, by the way. And saying that `sort` clears and injects a `SORTED` at the same time doesn’t make much sense, especially, as it is stable…

Comment: This table only reflects the **current** state of the implemantation. **Why** Did they inject/clear flags in terminal operations is an intersting question that should be investigated also. Thanks for the notes & edits.

Comment: Well, there is some kind of back-propagation of an *unsorted* terminal operation to the stream pipeline, which *may* have an effect on the operation, however, it’s more complicated, e.g. a `Collector` may be [`UNORDERED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED), therefore, a `collect` operation may propagate an *unordered* state to the stream pipeline. For other characteristics, it would be more interesting, whether a terminal operation may utilize it, e.g. `toArray` will benefit from a `SIZED` characteristic, `count` will in Java 9…

Answer (score 1):

It's sort of sounds like two duplicates - since both the answers that you linked actually explain things. I can't tell if `map` or `filter` should specifically say that they preserver order; they don't rely on any *previous* state or any other state (these are stateless operations) so it is *implied* that they preserve order as far as I can see. I see it the other way around, if they don't preserver order - that should be explicitly mentioned in the docs; if it not obvious from the name of the operation.
For example `Stream.generate` is not obvious to me if it generated an ordered stream; thus this is said in the documentation of it:

> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier.

`sorted` and `unordered` on the other hand are pretty obvious (IMO) to change order, at least when you put these in - you are explicitly saying that you do not care about the order. `unordered` btw will not do any randomizations on purpose to satisfy this, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944973/search-for-example-of-inconsistent-behavior-java-8-stream).

There are two orders in general: *processing order* and *encounter order*.

You can think about *encounter order* as processing from left to right (imagine you have a `List` or an `array`). So if you have a pipeline that does not change order - elements will be fed to the `Collector` (or any other terminal operation) as seen from left to right. Well not *all* terminal operations are like this. One obvious difference is `forEach` and `forEachOrdered`; or a `Collectors.toSet` - which does not need to preserver the initial order at all. Or let's take `findAny` as the terminal operation - obviously you don't care which element you want, so why bother feeding the `findAny` in an exact order in the first place?

*Processing order* on the other hand has no defined order - especially visible for parallel processing obviously. So even if your pipeline is parallel (and elements are processed with absolutely no guarantee of any order), they will still be fed to the terminal operation in order - if such an order is needed for that terminal operation.

Comment: I would go so far to say that *every* method that returns an *unordered* stream is documented as such. This also applies to `unordered()` whose documentation states that it returns an unordered stream, whereas `sorted()` does respect the encounter order, as it will use a stable sorting for ordered streams.